# A question about region around the maximum of a function

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, maxima-minima

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is a compact set, and $f:A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a continuous function with a unique point of maximum $x_0$.

I want to understand what are the minimal assumptions on $f$ for which there exists an open set $U$ containing $x_0$, and some $\alpha>0$ such that:

1. $\forall x \in U$, $f(x) > f(x_0) - \alpha$
2. $\forall x \in A\setminus \bar{U}$, $f(x) < f(x_0) - \alpha$

For example, if we assume that the function $f$ is smooth, then we can do a Taylor's series expansion around $x_0$ to get:

$ f(x_0 + th) = f(x_0) + \frac{t^2}{2}h^T(\nabla^2f(x_0))h + o(t^2)$ which means that for form $t_0$ small enough, we have for all $t \leq t_0$,

$f(x_0 + th) - f(x_0) \leq -\lambda_0t^2/2$

I want to know whether we can obtain similar result without the assumption of the existence of the Hessian.

Comment: The open set $U$ should be open in $\Bbb R^n$ or open in $A$?

Comment: Is'n better  for  1. >  and for 2. $\leq$

Other wise your own argument for smooth does not work!

Comment: @ajotatxe I had an open subset of $A$ in mind, but I am not sure if  that should be a problem.  If $U$ is an open subset of $R^n$, can we not take its intersection with the interior of $A$?

Comment: @Ashkan Yes, I think you are right. I had the closure of $U$,  $\bar{U}$ in mind for the second point. I think that should make sense.

Comment: I think still you need to consider  $>$ for 1

Comment: @ashkan thanks, I have changed it.

Comment: OK, sorry ! So I will delete my pervious comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Under the condition  that $x_0$ is the only maximum point (local and global).**

Take any $\alpha$   such that   $\max\{ \min f, ~ 0 \}   < \alpha  < f(x_0) .$

Now set  $U:= \{ x \in A ~ | f(x)  > f(x_0)  - \alpha  \}$ . Then $U$ and $V= A \setminus \bar{U}$ are two open set in $A$ satisfying $1,2$

P.S under our assumption we made here one can show that 
$$  V= \{ x \in A ~ | f(x)  < f(x_0)  - \alpha  \}   $$

Comment: Thanks. I think if we add a further assumption that the next best local maximum is at least $\Delta$ sub-optimal then I think we can take any $\alpha < \Delta$ to get this.

Comment: Yes,  All assumptions that guarantees 

$\partial U = \{  x \in A ~ |  f(x) = f(x_0)  - \alpha  \} $  works!

@panini